# Javascript Selector for custom Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to be able to get the .val() of a custom parameter within an  tag. The tag looks like this:

```
option style="font-weight: normal" answerid="32" >text here< /option
```

For the sake of the code / tag being self explanatory, I wanted to use "answerid" instead of "name" but I can't figure out how to get the value of that. My current script looks like this:

```
<script>
$('select').change(function () {
     var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
     var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val("answerid");
     $.get("ticket.php?do=quickanswer&selected=" +valueSelected+ "", 
     function( data ) {
                $( ".quickanswer" ).html( data );
                });

     console.log(valueSelected);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: "tag" in HTML typically refers to HTML elements, the word you're looking for is "attribute". If you want your markup to be valid, you should be using a [`[data-*]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**:

```
var valueSelected  = optionSelected.attr("answerid");
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bH7tk/)**

Answer (score 0):

Using `answerid` as an attribute is invalid HTML. Instead of using invalid markup, use a custom [`[data-*]` attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes):

```
<option data-answer-id="32">text here</option>
```

You can then take advantage of [jQuery's `.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data) to access the value:

```
answerId = optionSelected.data('answerId'); //32
```

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) works as well:

```
answerId = optionSelected.attr('data-answer-id'); //'32'
```

[Please see my related answer for details as to why you'd use one over the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262427/497418)